# In WPF/Silverlight is it possible to bind to an HTML-like TableControl?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding, itemscontrol

Given the following categories & subcategories:

1. Animations (Family Guy, Calvin & Hobes, The Boondocks, Duck Tales, Looney Toons, Pink & The Brain)
2. Sesame Street (Oscar, Ernie & Bert, Kermit de Frog, Elmo, Cookie Monster, Grover)

I am looking for a way to render it (dynamically) in to rows and columns as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Animations                                       |
----------------------------------------------------
| Family Guy  | Calvin & Hobes | The Boondocks     |
----------------------------------------------------
| Duck Tales  | Looney Toons   | Pinky & The Brain |
----------------------------------------------------
| Sesame Street                                    |
----------------------------------------------------
| Oscar       | Ernie & Bert   | Kermit de Frog    |
----------------------------------------------------
| Elmo        | Cookie Monster | Grover            |
----------------------------------------------------
```

P/S: I am aware of the list controls (ItemsControl, DataGrid, ListView etc.) and non of them seem to meet this criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do is create a query that somehow groups your items by categories (either you already have that or you can use linq to create your hierarchy through a Group By ... Into query).

Then you can use an ItemsControl that binds to the query result, displaying the data with an ItemTemplate containing a header and another ItemsControl which has an ItemsPanelTemplate set to a WrapPanel or a UniformGrid.

Assuming you manage to get your data in the following classes (sorry, VB here but C# would not be far from that if you need it):

```
Public Class Category

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property CategoryName() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _SubCategories As New List(Of SubCategory)
    Public Property SubCategories() As List(Of SubCategory)
        Get
            Return _SubCategories
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of SubCategory))
            _SubCategories = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class SubCategory

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property SubCategoryName() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class



<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QueryResult}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="Black">

                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                            
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                       Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
                        </Border>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                                BorderBrush="Black">

                                            <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                                       Text="{Binding SubCategoryName}" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This is a very rough template, you'll have to tinker with the borders to get what you need, but that would do the trick.

Comment: UniformGrid doesn't exist in silverlight, So I used this custom code: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/

Comment: True, it is missing and I use one that I have lying around because it can be SO useful...

Comment: another UniformGrid implementation for Silverlight http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2010/03/uniformgrid-for-silverlight-ported-from.html